# CSS Background Gradient Not Working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I'm using JQuery UI's default theme (sunny, if that matters) through Google CDN. I want to replace the default background for `ui-widget-header` with a CSS background gradient. This is my sample usage:-

```
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Some Title</h3>
```

My CSS looks like this:-

```
.ui-widget-header {
    background: #003366; /* default */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top center, #FFFFFF, #003366);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.00, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1.00, #003366));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top center, #FFFFFF, #003366);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#003366'); /* IE6 & IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#003366')"; /* IE8 */
}
```

This works for Firefox and Safari, but IE 8 is picking up the default background and the filter doesn't do anything.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Works in my IE8.  http://jsfiddle.net/grQN4/

Comment: Works in IE8, but in compatibilty mode (IE7) doesn't works.

Comment: @James, I tried your sample, it works on IE8. I think it has something to do with JQuery. I'm not running through compatibility mode, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an issue with IE7/8 that they don't set the gradient background if the element doesn't have height defined (hasLayout).

Try adding **zoom: 1**. If it doesn't work, you'll probably have to set a height, so try **height: 100%**.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, but I got the solution. Try this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#81a8cb', endColorstr='#ffffff'); /* For IE6 & IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#81a8cb', endColorstr='#ffffff')"; /* for IE8 */
```

Answer (score 3):

MS's IE filters often won't override a background-image, which the .ui-widget-header has. Try setting a 1px background image to the #003366 color and see if that fixes the issue.

Alternatively, `.ui-widget-header {background-image: none;}`

Comment: I tried setting the background size to 0 and background image to none, but they didn't work for me. I don't think there's a need to override background image, simply because I'm seeing the solid default color from my CSS, and not JQuery's background... but somehow the filter doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awesome resource that not only answers gradient questions (which is further down the webpage), but it also solves IE 7 8 9 problems with transparency, border radius, box & text shadows, and background color transparencies.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/